# What type is an object name?

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering what type I would have to call when my program has to know that my user input is an object name.

Example:

If I have this object in a class

```
Jens = Person("Jens", "14 years")

search = input("What person do you want to print info about? ") 

search.printInfo()
```

What type should I wrap around search to make it possible to set it into my printInfo function?

Thanks in advance

I am working in python3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: Put your objects into a dictionary and use the name as a key. If you want to retrieve it by more than one attribute, put it in multiple dictionaries. Or else use a database.

Comment: I am trying to create a database and I have a dictionary. I just can't print one single key which is what I want

Comment: Not a duplicate at all. I want to know what type the object is thx

Comment: Say you have `x = 5`.  The name `x` isn't a python object.  You can access the mappings of names to objects using the `globals` and `locals`. functions, but it makes much more sense to simply have a separate dictionary that you own and can pass around between functions.

Comment: If I have a dictionary then and I want to print just one of the keys instead of all.

Comment: How do i search just one single key and print that particular key?

Comment: You don't have to search at all; it's just a key in the dictionary, so you can access it directly. `my_dict[my_key]`

Comment: I see but I can't access one specific key. If I have 

dict = {Gertrud: 5, James: 4, Bente: 5}

How do I print only James? Without printing the others